# SQL: list users with their phone numbers and email addresses

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to make a query in PostgreSQL which lists my users and their email addresses and phone numbers (separated by commas), like this:

```
| user1 | email1@mail.com, email2@mail.com | +3612123123, +3623234234 |
```

The tables are:

```
user - stores the user's data

user_email - stores the user's email addresses

user_phone - stores the user's phone numbers
```

I tried the obvius:

```
SELECT user.id, user.name
(
  SELECT array_agg(user_email.email)
  FROM user_email
  WHERE user_email.user_id = user.id
) AS EmailAddresses,
(
  SELECT array_agg(user_phone.phone)
  FROM user_phone
  WHERE user_phone.user_id = user.id
) AS PhoneNumbers
FROM user
ORDER BY user.id
```

But this lead to ridiculous query times (34sec).
Than I tried:

```
SELECT user.id, user.name, array_agg(user_email.email), array_agg(user_phone.phone)
FROM user
LEFT JOIN user_email ON user_email.user_id = user.id
LEFT JOIN user_phone ON user_phone.user_id = user.id
GROUP BY user.id
ORDER BY user.id
```

This results very good query times (around 100ms).
But this way it's lists every combination of phone numbers and email addresses. So if I have 3 email address and 3 phone number, then it lists 9 email address (triples every single address) and 9 phone numbers too.

Is there an efficient way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DISTINCT` can be used within [aggregate expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) too:

```
SELECT "user".id, name, array_agg(DISTINCT email) emails, array_agg(DISTINCT phone) phones
FROM "user"
LEFT JOIN user_email ON user_email.user_id = "user".id
LEFT JOIN user_phone ON user_phone.user_id = "user".id
GROUP BY "user".id
ORDER BY "user".id;
```

Note: if you only need comma separated lists, you may want to use [`string_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) instead of `array_agg()`.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5b886b/4)

Answer (score 0):

Either `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.id, user.name, array_agg(user_email.email), array_agg(user_phone.phone)
FROM user
LEFT JOIN user_email ON user_email.user_id = user.id
LEFT JOIN user_phone ON user_phone.user_id = user.id
GROUP BY user.id
ORDER BY user.id
```

Or `INNER` Joins

```
SELECT user.id, user.name, array_agg(user_email.email), array_agg(user_phone.phone)
FROM user
INNER JOIN user_email ON user_email.user_id = user.id
INNER JOIN user_phone ON user_phone.user_id = user.id
GROUP BY user.id
ORDER BY user.id
```

Or both

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.id, user.name, array_agg(user_email.email), array_agg(user_phone.phone)
FROM user
INNER JOIN user_email ON user_email.user_id = user.id
INNER JOIN user_phone ON user_phone.user_id = user.id
GROUP BY user.id
ORDER BY user.id
```

Comment: There is no need to add `distinct` if you use `group by`